# Adding Jars (More than One) to maven Classpath is giving errors

Tags: java, maven, classpath

There are multiple jars (10 jars) and I have to use them in classpath in maven project.
These jars are available in my Project-dir/lib folder.

To handle this I tried

```
<build>         
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>lib/*.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

changed     lib/*.jar to
1. lib
2. /lib
etc but nothing seems working

Also tried

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>in-project</id>
            <name>In Project Repo</name>
            <url>lib/*.jar</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

But always faced error (cannot find symbol) on running mvn install

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jars as dependencies for build or test, they should be inside a Maven repository (not in a `lib` folder in your project).

The best thing would be to upload them to your company Nexus/Artifactory (if they are not already available from MavenCentral or some other remote Maven repository).

Alternatively, you can use `mvn install:install-file` to install them to the local repository on your computer.

After that, you can reference them in the `pom.xml` as dependencies.

Also see: [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/927493)